# How to upload image in mongodb using nodejs express? And how to test using postman?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

Not use temporary location Image taken from front end as request data-stream and store into database

```
exports.saveimage = function(req, res, next) {
    var imgPath = '/Users/Documents/logo.png';
    var logoimage = new LogoImage(req.body);

    logoimage.Photo.data = fs.readFileSync(imgPath);
    logoimage.Photo.contentType = 'image/png';

    logoimage.save(function (err, logoimage) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).send({
                message:'unable to save'
            });
        } else {
            res.json(logoimage);
            console.error('saved img to mongo');
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/